# Extracting specific text from pdf/rtf

Tags: r, pdf, text-extraction, data-extraction

I have a large scanned document (as a PDF but have converted it to a .rtf if that is easier) containing vet reports for multiple different animals. I am trying to extract only some of the data about each animal to be able to put it into a spreadsheet. All of the notes are laid out the same with the heading before the information and separated with spaces.

I need the information following: Animal, Age, Type, Gender, lab ref, sample date, received date. and then for each item on the list below that (Total Protein, Albumin, ...etc) just the number in the next column. I have tried using:

```
read.delim("Text file")
grep( "animal", "Text file")
```

but I don't think that's the right command.

[image]

Comment: If you want to extract from PDF, you should use the pdftools package.  The content in a PDF file is usually in a compressed stream.  You can't just grep it.  First you have to get it out of the PDF, and then manipulate it.